# Using CLUZ plugin in QGIS 3.4.2?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I wanted to install the plugins CLUZ and Marxan in QGIS, but both do not appear when you search for them in the plugins sections...

Does anyone know why this is the case, or how can I use CLUZ then?

(I downloaded the latest version Madeira 3.4.2 today)

Comment: CLUZ plugin available only for QGIS 2.x. You can check it on the http://plugins.qgis.org//plugins/cluz/ page.

Comment: There's a new version of CLUZ that works on QGIS 3.X

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with these plugins, but it appears that the CLUZ  plugin is not compatible with QGIS 3.4. It's maximum verion is 2.99 (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/cluz/version/2018.7.3/). In QGIS 3.x the Marxan plugin is replaced with the QMarxanToolbox, so you can try that. You probably should use QGIS 2.x to use the CLUZ plugin, or hopefully the plugin will be updated soon. You could also try version 3.0. You can find the older versions from this link http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/.